# Oracle MapViewer / Map Builder - Tile algorithm

Tags: oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

Oracle MapBuilder generates three types of layers - theme, base and tiles. 
I try to create algorithm for tiled layers. Have you any idea how to decode this?

I mean algorithm for width and height of tiles.

For a tiles is generated XML like this:

```
<map_tile_layer name="TL_TEST" image_format="PNG" http_header_expires="168.0" concurrent_fetching_threads="3">
   <internal_map_source data_source="10.0.0.57_lrs" base_map="BM_AGC" bgcolor="none"/>
   <tile_storage root_path="/temp"/>
   <coordinate_system srid="2180" minX="-413374.575" minY="193748.248" maxX="1418971.699" maxY="766162.025"/>
   <tile_image width="256" height="256"/>
   <zoom_levels levels="11" min_scale="1.0" max_scale="1.0E7" min_tile_width="0.06773333184979038" min_tile_height="610782.0913333333">
     <zoom_level level="0" name="level0" description="" scale="1.0E7" tile_width="610782.0913333333" tile_height="610782.0913333333">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="1" name="level1" description="" scale="1000000.0" tile_width="65440.938357142855" tile_height="65440.938357142855">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="2" name="level2" description="" scale="100000.0" tile_width="6761.425365313653" tile_height="6761.425365313653">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="3" name="level3" description="" scale="10000.0" tile_width="677.1420081300813" tile_height="677.1420081300813">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="4" name="level4" description="" scale="1000.0" tile_width="67.73172195320296" tile_height="67.73172195320296">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="5" name="level5" description="" scale="100.0" tile_width="6.773322418713311" tile_height="6.773322418713311">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="6" name="level6" description="" scale="10.0" tile_width="0.677333243384311" tile_height="0.677333243384311">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="7" name="level7" description="" scale="5.0" tile_width="0.3386666216921555" tile_height="0.3386666216921555">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="8" name="level8" description="" scale="4.0" tile_width="0.2709332973537244" tile_height="0.2709332973537244">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="9" name="level9" description="" scale="2.0" tile_width="0.13546665869200755" tile_height="0.13546665869200755">
     </zoom_level>
     <zoom_level level="10" name="level10" description="" scale="1.0" tile_width="0.06773333184979038" tile_height="0.06773333184979038">
     </zoom_level>
   </zoom_levels>
</map_tile_layer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar algorithm, with minimal difference.

```
scale * 2.54 * tile width(pixels) / (96dpi*100)
```

This is sufficient response.